# Copy and paste data from a excel file to another and change the format

Tags: excel, vba

I have one specific column in an excel file with date in this format:
202010
**--> That means year and month.**

I want to copy that to another workbook but separate the month (10) in one column and the year in the next column (2020).
And on the 3rd column add a value in this format: 01/10/2020.

I've been struggling with this, I've tried so many different things but none worked the way I want.
Could you please give me a light????

Thanks!

Comment: You can do that with formulas, no VBA needed, right?

Answer (score 0):

### Split Date

- Adjust the values in the constants section.
- It is assumed that the source column contains valid data in the format `yyyym` or `yyyymm`, or 'invalid' data with less than 5 or more than 6 characters when there will be no transformation.
- s - source, d - destination.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub splitDate()
    
    Const sName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const sFirst As String = "A2"
    Const dFirst As String = "A2"

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Define Source Column Range.
    Dim srg As Range
    With wb.Worksheets(sName).Range(sFirst)
        Set srg = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        If srg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        Set srg = .Resize(srg.Row - .Row + 1)
    End With
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = srg.Rows.Count
    
    ' Write value from Source Column Range to Data Array.
    Dim Data As Variant
    If rCount = 1 Then
        ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1): Data(1, 1) = srg.Value
    Else
        Data = srg.Value
    End If
    
    ' Resize Data Array.
    ReDim Preserve Data(1 To rCount, 1 To 3)
    
    ' Declare additional variables
    Dim r As Long
    Dim sValue As String
    Dim dYear As Long
    Dim dMonth As Long
    
    ' Write resulting values to (resized) Data Array.
    For r = 1 To rCount
        If Len(sValue) > 4 And Len(sValue) < 7 Then
            sValue = CStr(Data(r, 1))
            dMonth = CLng(Right(sValue, Len(sValue) - 4))
            dYear = CLng(Left(sValue, 4))
            Data(r, 1) = dMonth
            Data(r, 2) = dYear
            Data(r, 3) = DateSerial(dYear, dMonth, 1)
        End If
    Next r
    
    ' Write values from Data Array to Destination Range.
    With Workbooks.Add.Worksheets(1).Range(dFirst).Resize(rCount, 3)
        ' If your date separator is a dot, then use "dd\/mm\/yyyy".
        .Columns(3).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
        .Value = Data
        .EntireColumn.AutoFit
        With .Worksheet.Parent ' Destination Workbook
            .Saved = True ' Only for easy closing while testing.
            'Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' overwrite without confirmation
            '.SaveAs "C:\Test\Dest.xlsx", xlOpenXMLWorkbook
            'Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            '.Close False
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the 202010 is in Cell A1

Formula: `=DATE(LEFT(A1,4),RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-4),1)`

VBA:

```
Format("01/" & right(Range("A1").Text,len(Range("A1").Text)-4) & "/" & left(Range("A1").Text,4),"DD/MM/YYYY")
```

Break this apart and you can see how I have constructed the date, you should be able to work out the Year and Month code form that.

Comment: Thanks Dan! The formula works yes, but the VBA works better for me!